# XAML PasswordBox throwing InvalidCastException during initialisation

Tags: c#, xaml

I am working on a Windows Forms application in C# with XAML.

When a class is loaded that contains a PasswordBox, the application always crashes with a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException at the last Parameter of the PasswordBox with an inner Exception: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Color' to type 'System.Windows.Style'.
This always occurs, even if I am using the simplest of PasswordBoxes

```
<PasswordBox x:Name"passwordBox" Height="30" Width="300"/>
```

The XamlParseException would, in this example, point to the Width attribute.

Anybody know where this error could be coming from or at least how to better debug it?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a blank new project with just that line on MainWindow?

Comment: Yes, with just that line in MainWindow it gives the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is somehow related to the passwordbox style, look in your application/window/usercontrol ressources, you may have a custom style that redifine the style of the passwordbox with a xaml error somewhere :)

Comment: That was it, just found out that for some reason a former developer of my project had added a resource style for the PasswordBox within the App.xaml file targeting all PasswordBoxes. Thank you very much :)